# What happens when we do a repartition on a dataframe that is already repartitioned?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I was analysing a developed code. I found something like this.

```
val newDF = df.repartition(1).withColumn("name", lit("xyz")).orderBy(col("count").asc)
```

Later at a different module, this `newDF` was reused as below

```
newDF.repartition(1).write.format("csv").save(path/of/file)
```

Now my doubt is, since the same dataframe is repartitioned in 2 places - that too with an `orderby` in place for the first Dataframe - Will the data not get shuffled after the second repartition which makes orderBy void ?